# How to connect FileMaker Pro 18 locally with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, database, connection, filemaker

How can I connect Filemaker Pro 18 locally with Laravel? Below is the environment file; I have added the IP provided by FileMaker Pro 18.

**.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=filemaker
DB_HOST=192.168.10.227
DB_DATABASE="Dev_Scan_Storage"
DB_USERNAME=SSI_ODBC
DB_PASSWORD=odbc
```

**database.php**

```
'filemaker' => [
        'driver' => 'filemaker',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'fms.mycompany.com'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'MyFileName'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'myusername'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'prefix' => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
        'version' => env('DB_VERSION', 'v18'),
        'protocol' => env('DB_PROTOCOL', 'http'),
    ],
```

I have tried Eloquent as well as the DB Raw method.

**Controller**

```
use App\Models\DEV_SCAN;
use BlueFeather\EloquentFileMaker\Support\Facades\FM;
use DB;

class getdataController extends Controller
{
    function get()
    {
        $user = DEV_SCAN::get();
        
        return view('welcome');
    }
}
```

I tried to use the APIs of FileMaker, but that didn't work as well. So I have FileMaker Pro 18 (client) installed. Also, I have turned on ODBC sharing and provided correct credentials, but still, it won't connect.

**Modal**

```
use BlueFeather\EloquentFileMaker\Database\Eloquent\FMModel;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class DEV_SCAN extends FMModel
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $layoutName = 'View ALL Records';
}
```

Comment: Have you opened the ODBC ports on the firewall?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to connect to FileMaker Server or FileMaker Pro? You can't connect to FileMaker Pro. Also note in the FileMaker Server admin console you need to enable ODBC sharing and install an ODBC driver. See here: https://help.claris.com/en/pro-help/content/odbc-jdbc.html "To share your FileMaker database file as a data source over a network, use FileMaker Server or FileMaker Cloud for AWS; files shared by FileMaker Pro or FileMaker Cloud cannot be accessed as data sources over a network."

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually i have file maker pro 18 and i have installed odbc drivers and also enabled it

Comment: Do you have FileMaker server? ODBC only works to FileMaker server,  not to pro.

Comment: can you give me a complete guide of how to connect laravel 8 with filemaker?

Comment: Probably better asking that on the FileMaker community forums: https://community.claris.com/en/s/question/0D50H00006h9E5kSAE/how-to-connect-a-laravel-web-application-to-a-filemaker-database

Comment: Also note I haven't used this but here is something that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70150597/how-to-connect-filemaker-pro-18-locally-with-laravel?noredirect=1#comment124272544_70150597

Answer (score 0):

This package depends on the FileMaker Data API, which is only available through FileMaker Server. You will not be able get data out of a file run through FileMaker Pro like this.

If you can get your database hosted on FMS it will work well for you.